# HoloLens application based on Unity not able to receive TCP data

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp, hololens

I am working on an application for the HoloLens (1) based on Unity. I am trying to send data via TCP from a Qt-based application (Windows) to the HoloLens. Wireshark shows, that my test package is correctly sent and acknowledged by the HoloLens. The data starts with four bytes containing the length of the message, which starts right after those four bytes. In the following code, first, the four bytes are trying to be received, and afterwards, the message itself.

After executing the code for connecting and sending the data in the client application, `StreamSocketListener_ConnectionReceived()` is called on the HoloLens. In the next `Update()` call, `ReadTcpData()` is called. Now, execution 'stops' at the first call to

```
tcpMessageSizeBuffer[tcpMessageSizeBytesRead++] = (byte)stream.ReadByte();
```

At least the debugger jumps out of the code when I try to step over the line. There is no exception caught in the catch block.

I was expecting that the `EndOfStream` property of `StreamReader` would be false if there is nothing to read, and consequently, I would receive a valid byte from the stream when calling `ReadByte` when it was true. I have no clue what goes wrong here. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

#if UNITY_WINRT && !UNITY_EDITOR
using Windows.Networking.Sockets;
using Windows.Networking;
using Windows.Networking.Connectivity;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
#endif

public class NetworkManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int tcpPort;

#if UNITY_WINRT && !UNITY_EDITOR
    private StreamSocketListener streamSocketListener;
    private StreamReader tcpStreamReader = null;
    private StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs connectionArgs;
    private DatagramSocket datagramSocket;
    private MemoryStream pendingDatagramSocketStream;
#endif

    private UInt32 tcpMessageSizeByteCount;
    private UInt32 tcpMessageSizeBytesRead;
    private byte[] tcpMessageSizeBuffer;

    private bool tcpMessageSizeReceived;

    private UInt32 tcpMessageByteCount;
    private UInt32 tcpMessageBytesRead;
    private byte[] tcpMessageBuffer;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Application.runInBackground = true;
        ResetTcpConnection();
    }

    public void ResetTcpConnection()
    {
#if UNITY_WINRT && !UNITY_EDITOR
        ResetTcpRead();

        if (streamSocketListener != null)
        {
            tcpStreamReader.Dispose();
            tcpStreamReader = null;
            connectionArgs = null;
            streamSocketListener.Dispose();
            streamSocketListener = null;
        }

        streamSocketListener = new StreamSocketListener();
        streamSocketListener.ConnectionReceived += this.StreamSocketListener_ConnectionReceived;
        streamSocketListener.BindServiceNameAsync(tcpPort.ToString());
#endif
    }

#if UNITY_WINRT && !UNITY_EDITOR
    // Process the client connection.
    private async void StreamSocketListener_ConnectionReceived(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        connectionArgs = args; // Keep this alive
        tcpStreamReader = new StreamReader(connectionArgs.Socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead());
    }
#endif

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
#if UNITY_WINRT && !UNITY_EDITOR
        if (tcpStreamReader != null && !tcpStreamReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            Stream stream = tcpStreamReader.BaseStream;
            ReadTcpData(ref stream);
        }
#endif
    }

    private void ResetTcpRead()
    {
        tcpMessageSizeByteCount = sizeof(UInt32);
        tcpMessageSizeBytesRead = 0;
        tcpMessageSizeBuffer = new byte[tcpMessageSizeByteCount];

        tcpMessageSizeReceived = false;

        tcpMessageByteCount = 0;
        tcpMessageBytesRead = 0;
        tcpMessageBuffer = null;
    }

    private void ReadTcpData(ref Stream stream)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!tcpMessageSizeReceived)
            {
#if UNITY_WINRT && !UNITY_EDITOR
                while(tcpMessageSizeBytesRead < tcpMessageSizeByteCount && !tcpStreamReader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    tcpMessageSizeBuffer[tcpMessageSizeBytesRead++] = (byte)stream.ReadByte();
                }

                if(tcpMessageSizeBytesRead == tcpMessageSizeByteCount)
                {
                    tcpMessageByteCount = BitConverter.ToUInt32(tcpMessageSizeBuffer, 0);
                }
#endif

                if (tcpMessageByteCount > 0)
                {
                    tcpMessageBuffer = new byte[tcpMessageByteCount];
                    tcpMessageSizeReceived = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Read the message
                int bytesToRead = (int)(tcpMessageByteCount - tcpMessageBytesRead);
                bytesToRead = bytesToRead > 10000 ? 10000 : bytesToRead;
                int bytesRead = stream.Read(tcpMessageBuffer, (int)tcpMessageBytesRead, bytesToRead);
                tcpMessageBytesRead += (uint)bytesRead;

                // Did we finish reading the message?
                if (tcpMessageBytesRead >= tcpMessageByteCount)
                {
                    ResetTcpRead();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem - I have to use `BinaryReader` and replace the code reading the length of the message such:

```
while(tcpMessageSizeBytesRead < tcpMessageSizeByteCount)
{
   tcpMessageSizeBuffer[tcpMessageSizeBytesRead++] = (byte)binaryReader.ReadByte();
}
```

For the sake of consistency, also the part of the code actually reading the message can be adapted to use `BinaryReader`.